How to implement Progressive Distillation for Diffusion Policy
The standard Diffusion Policy uses this training loop to train a diffusion model conditioned on a latent observation space to predict robot action sequences (adapted from https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18GIHeOQ5DyjMN8iIRZL2EKZ0745NLIpg?usp=sharing#scrollTo=VrX4VTl5pYNq). I now want to create a progressive distiallation trainer that halves the steps needed to sample.
Question:
In this simplistic example the student-timestep is a number between 0 and 1 and then the teacher is double that.
the Training Loop I want to adapt, it is a random vector: 64 times number from 1 to 100 [1,30,26,60,...] Should I just half that vector? My guess is, in the other training loop the batch has 64 examples to make the training faster. Thanks!
For a simple example (mre) I created this code:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np

class SimpleUNet(nn.Module):
    """A minimal UNet-like architecture for the diffusion model"""
    def __init__(self, in_channels=1, out_channels=1, base_channels=16):
        super().__init__()
        # Adjust first convolution to handle time embedding
        self.enc1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels + 1, base_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(base_channels)
        )
        self.enc2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(base_channels, base_channels*2, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(base_channels*2)
        )
        
        # Decoder
        self.dec2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(base_channels*2, base_channels, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(base_channels)
        )
        self.dec1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(base_channels*2, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.Tanh()
        )
    
    def forward(self, x, t):
        # Add time embedding as an additional channel
        t_embed = torch.sin(t.unsqueeze(-1).unsqueeze(-1).expand_as(x[:,:1,:,:]))
        x = torch.cat([x, t_embed], dim=1)
        
        # Encoder
        x1 = self.enc1(x)
        x2 = self.enc2(x1)
        
        # Decoder
        x3 = self.dec2(x2)
        x4 = torch.cat([x3, x1], dim=1)
        return self.dec1(x4)

class ProgressiveDiffusion:
    def __init__(self, student_steps=4, teacher_steps=8):
        self.student_steps = student_steps
        self.teacher_steps = teacher_steps
        
        # Teacher and student models
        self.teacher_model = SimpleUNet()
        self.student_model = SimpleUNet()
        
        self.teacher_optimizer = optim.Adam(self.teacher_model.parameters())
        self.student_optimizer = optim.Adam(self.student_model.parameters())
        
        self.loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()
    
    def noise_image(self, x, t):
        """Add noise to input image based on timestep"""
        noise = torch.randn_like(x)
        return x * (1.0 - t.view(-1, 1, 1, 1)) + noise * t.view(-1, 1, 1, 1)
    
    def train_teacher(self, dataset, epochs=50):
        """Train initial teacher model with more diffusion steps"""
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            for batch in dataset:
                self.teacher_optimizer.zero_grad()
                
                # Sample random timestep
                t = torch.rand(batch.size(0))
                
                # Add noise to image
                noisy_x = self.noise_image(batch, t)
                
                # Predict noise
                predicted_noise = self.teacher_model(noisy_x, t)
                loss = self.loss_fn(predicted_noise, torch.randn_like(batch))
                
                loss.backward()
                self.teacher_optimizer.step()
    
    def progressive_distillation(self, dataset):
        """Perform progressive distillation from teacher to student"""
        # Train teacher first
        self.train_teacher(dataset)
        
        # Prepare for distillation
        for epoch in range(100):
            epoch_losses = []
            for batch in dataset:
                self.student_optimizer.zero_grad()
                
                # Sample student and teacher timesteps
                student_t = torch.rand(batch.size(0)) * (self.student_steps / self.teacher_steps)
                teacher_t = student_t * (self.teacher_steps / self.student_steps) # double the student timestep
                """Question 1: Timesteps
                In this simplistic example the student-timestep is a number between 0 and 1
                In the Training Loop I want to adapt, it is a random vector: 64 times number from 1 to 100 [1,30,26,60,...]
                Should I just half that vector? My guess is, in the other training loop the batch has 64 examples to make the training faster.            
                
                """
                # Add noise to both
                noisy_x_student = self.noise_image(batch, student_t)
                noisy_x_teacher = self.noise_image(batch, teacher_t)
                
                # Get teacher and student predictions
                with torch.no_grad():
                    teacher_pred = self.teacher_model(noisy_x_teacher, teacher_t)
                
                student_pred = self.student_model(noisy_x_student, student_t)
                
                # Distillation loss
                loss = self.loss_fn(student_pred, teacher_pred.detach())
                
                
                epoch_losses.append(loss.item())
                loss.backward()
                self.student_optimizer.step()

            print(f"Epoch: {epoch}, mean epoch_losses: {np.mean(epoch_losses)}" )
    
    def sample(self, x, steps):
        """Sample from the model"""
        x_t = x
        for t in reversed(range(steps)):
            t_tensor = torch.full((x.size(0),), t / steps)
            noise_pred = self.student_model(x_t, t_tensor)
            x_t = x_t - noise_pred
        return x_t

# Example usage
def generate_simple_dataset():
    """Generate a simple synthetic dataset of random images"""
    return torch.rand(100, 1, 28, 28)

# Main execution
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create dataset
    dataset = generate_simple_dataset()
    
    # Initialize and train progressive distillation
    diffusion = ProgressiveDiffusion()
    diffusion.progressive_distillation(dataset) # halving the steps from 8 to 4
    
    # Generate a sample
    initial_noise = torch.randn(1, 1, 28, 28)
    print(f"initial_noise: {initial_noise}")
    generated_sample = diffusion.sample(initial_noise, steps=4)
    print(f"generated_sample: {generated_sample}")

    print("Sample generated successfully!")

